# NodeJS - Passing command line parameters to a required module

Tags: node.js, express, command-line-interface, pm2

This is my folder structure for an ExpressJS application that exposes a couple of APIs.

```
/
|_ index.js
|_ app
   |_ server.js
|_routes
  |_route1.js
```

I start the application with `pm2` as:
`pm2 start index.js --name server1 -- $HOME/cfg/config.json`

In `index.js`, I have `require(./app/server)` where `server.js` needs a few parameters from `$HOME/cfg/config.json`. Since the configuration file is passed as arguments to `index.js`, I am not sure, how to pass the parameters to `server.js`. Can you please advise?

`index.js`

```
var fs = require('fs')
var app = require('./app/server');
var http = require('http');
//
var launchServer = function(err, config) {
  server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(config.port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
}
//
function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}
//
function onListening() {
 /** 

 How to pass server object ??


  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
*/
  console.log('Server started.')
}
//
var getConfig = function(launchServer, configFile) {
  fs.readFile(configFile, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    launchServer(null, JSON.parse(data))
  })
}
//
getConfig(launchServer, process.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js command line arguments are available on process and process is available globally so already available without having to pass the data.